# Bootstrap a function with multiple arguments using scipy.stats.bootstrap

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to compute the Standard Error of an estimate using `scipy.stats.bootstrap`. The function I am using takes two arguments. E.g. I have two lists like:

```py
x = [12, 14, 82, 55, 63, 56]
w = [0.61, 1.01, 1.8, 2.6, 0.93, 1.13]
```

An I would like to bootstrap a function similar to:

```py
import numpy as np
np.average(x, weights=w) # <- Or any other function that takes 2 or more arguments.
```

I have tried:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import bootstrap

x = [12, 14, 82, 55, 63, 56]
w = [0.61, 1.01, 1.8, 2.6, 0.93, 1.13]

# I tried converting 2 arguments into only 1.
def weighted_mean(z):
    return np.average(z[0], weights=z[1])

bootstrap(((np.array(x), np.array(w) ), ),
                        statistic=weighted_mean,
                        confidence_level=0.95, axis=0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

How can I compute the Standard Error using `scipy.stats.bootstrap` for that function or a similar one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary relating each value to its weight, with a unique identifier for each pair. You'll use this identifier as a key of your dictionary, and then you'll use this dictionary in the `weighted_mean` function.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import bootstrap
x = [12, 12, 14, 82, 55, 63, 56]
w = [0.61,2.07, 1.01, 1.8, 2.6, 0.93, 1.13]
identifiers = [i for i in range(len(x))]

#we create the mapping dictionary
data = zip(x,w)
dict_x_w =  {identifier:(value,weight) for identifier, (value, weight) in enumerate(data)}


def weighted_mean(z, axis):
    #creating an array of weights, by mapping z to dict_x_w    
    data = np.vectorize(dict_x_w.get)(z)
    
    return np.average(data[0], weights=data[1], 
                      axis=axis)

bootstrap( (identifiers,), 
           statistic=weighted_mean, 
           confidence_level=0.95, 
           axis=0)
>>> BootstrapResult(confidence_interval=ConfidenceInterval(low=23.18201516793067, high=64.45438583045959), standard_error=10.622499830792794)
```

Unless you add a parameter "vectorized=False" when calling the bootstrap function, you also have to add a parameter "axis" in the `weighted_mean` function, otherwise you'll get an error message.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it would not work if you have a repeated value in `x`  with a different weight (`w`) associated to it. E.g. ```x = [12, 12, 82] w = [0.61, 1.01, 1.8]```  would return a dict with length 2: `{12: 1.01, 82: 1.8}`, where the weight of the first element in `x` would be replaced by that of the second.

Comment: @JosepEspasa Indeed, I missed this problem. I updated the solution to take that into account, hopefully it should work now.